# Which operations on what type of classes invalidates an Eigen:Ref?

Tags: c++, eigen3

I came across the following behavior with Eigen::Ref :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{
  Eigen::VectorXf a = Eigen::Vector2f{1,2};
  Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXf> ref{a};

  std::cout << a.transpose() << "\n";     // prints: 1, 2
  std::cout << ref.transpose() << "\n";   // prints: 1, 2

  a = Eigen::Vector3f{3,4,5};

  std::cout << a.transpose() << "\n";     // prints: 3, 4, 5
  std::cout << ref.transpose() << "\n";   // prints: 3, 4
  return 0;
}
```

The invalidation of Eigen references does not seem to be documented as far as I can tell. When does it occur?

Comment: I'd say it deserves a mention at least

Comment: Sorry, in second thought I do agree it deserves a mention. Couldn't find one myself.